# solr query exception ! how is that going on?

Tags: solr

i use solr 4.3 for my website ,
whie i query one data with morelike this function ,
sometime this exception goes out :

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: parsing error
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.java:43)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:385)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
```

parsing error??
how was it ?
why it occures ?
thanks for your reply .

this code :
the code :

```
public MoreLikeThisQueryResponse(QueryResponse queryResponse) {
    this.queryResponse = queryResponse;

    NamedList<Object> res = this.queryResponse.getResponse();
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
      String name = res.getName(i);
      if ("match".equals(name)) {
        this.matchResult = (SolrDocumentList) res.getVal(i);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the request you send to Solr before fetching the results? It's very likely that this is the cause of the parse exception.

Answer (score 0):

This type of "parsing error" in the BinaryResponseParser.processResponse method typically indicates that the server is returning a raw HTML text response rather than a Solr javabin response. Typically that means that the server container (Tomcat or Jetty) is detecting and reporting an error before Solr gets a chance to handle the error and obey the wt parameter which sets the response format to javabin.

Check the server log for the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

It seems that there might be a compatibility error is your are not using the EXACT compatible versions of Solr and Solrj.

To resolve this, you have to specify

```
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
```

Quoting from [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)

> SolrJ generally maintains backwards compatibility, so you can use a newer SolrJ with an older Solr, or an older SolrJ with a newer Solr. There are some minor exceptions to this general rule:
>
> If you're mixing 1.x and a later major version, you must set the response parser to XML, because the two versions use incompatible versions of javabin.